# jquery .clone() weird behaviour in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, clone

I have a following issue - I'm using jQuery to add additional input forms to the page. But added rows are not passed to the server with form submission.

Here is HTML of one row:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">

<div id="input1" class="clonedInput">

<label for="answer1" class="answer_label"> Answer: </label>
<input type="text" name="answer1" id="answer1" value="Answ1"/>
<label for="answer1pt"> Points: </label>
<input type="text" name="answer1pt" id="answer1pt" size="2" value="1"/>
```

for cloning I use following JavaScript:

```
$('#btnAddAnswer').click(function() {

var num  = $('.clonedInput').length;
var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum); 

newElem.find(":nth-child(1)").attr('for', 'answer' + newNum);
newElem.find(":nth-child(2)").attr('id', 'answer' + newNum).attr('name', 'answer' + newNum).attr('value', '');
newElem.find(":nth-child(3)").attr('for', 'answer' + newNum + 'pt');
newElem.find(":nth-child(4)").attr('id', 'answer' + newNum + 'pt').attr('name', 'answer' + newNum + 'pt').attr('value', ''); 

$('#input' + num).after(newElem);
$('#btnDelAnswer').attr('disabled','');

if (newNum == 5)
        $('#btnAddAnswer').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

So basically I first clone div with all content and then just adjust id's and other attributes.

The problem is that when running this code, everything displays on the page and seems ok, but when I submit the form, it appears that only first element is sent to the server.

This code perfectly works in Chrome and even IE, but not in Firefox. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or what might cause this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using an add-on like Firebug so you can see the html output of the javascript, see if there is anything amiss there.

Comment: Already chechked it - HTML is ok. Seems to be some kind of FF bug. Any ideas how to do the same using other jQuery methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Thanks [Gazler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219743/gazler), although there was no problem with actual HTML and Firefox error console didn't show any messages, I checked Developers Tools in Chrome and it said that div tag was inside table body, which, apparently, caused all the troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Can I strongly recommend that you try to clean up your selectors by using classes instead of nth-child? It'll make all of your code a lot more readable. For example, if you had markup like:

```
<label class="answer-label" for="answer1">...</label>
<input type="text" class="answer-box" name="answer1" class="answer1" />
```

Then you could use this prettier Javascript:

```
newElem.find(".answer-label").attr('for', 'answer' + newNum);
```

Also, you might want to consider just storing one variable instead of num and newNum. That way, each time you can just do `num++;` instead of doing `var newNum = new Number(num+1);`. (I'm also not sure why you do `new Number(num+1)` instead of just `var newNum = num+1;`.

When in doubt, clean up your code and things might just fix themselves.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, but still it doesn't work.
Actually I borrowed this code from one blog (http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/9/17/jQuery--Dynamically-Adding-Form-Elements) and didn't bother myself to clean it up.